# How to create a keyframe smooth continuous loop that doesn't jump with a background image?

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have created a div with a background image.  Using keyframe animation I want it to move vertically up continuously, which it does however at the end of the frame it jumps then continues.  I am new with keyframes.  I can not use JS.

I have tried looking at the questions on here but they are mainly focused on sliders.

This is my code so far:

```
<style>
#animate-area   { 
    background-image: url(/image.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 5s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 5s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: animatedBackground 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
   from { background-position: 0 0; }
   to { background-position: 0 100%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
   from { background-position: 0 0; }
   to { background-position: 0 100%; }
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
   from { background-position: 0 0; }
   to { background-position: 0 100%; }
}
</style>

<div id="animate-area"></div>
```

As soon as the frame has finished it jumps and then continues.  Is it possible to for it to continuously loop without jumping with a background image? If so, how?

Comment: would alternate be enough ?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction

Comment: Thank you for the link.  It stopped the jumping but moved the image up and down, I need it to continuously move up but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Live example to continuously move up :

```css
#animate-area {
  background-image: url('https://pt.freelogodesign.org/Content/img/logo-ex-2.png');
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;

  background-position: 0;
 animation: slideup 5s linear 1s infinite;
 
 position:absolute;
}

@keyframes slideup {
  0% { background-position: 0 0; }
  50% { background-position: 0 -500px; }
  100% { background-position: 0 -900px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="animate-area"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use twice the same image with opposite coordonates to move from/to :

```css
#animate-area {
  background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/100&text=img_1), url(http://dummyimage.com/100&text=img_2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 0 -100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation: animatedBackground 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0, 0 -100%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 100%, 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="animate-area"></div>
```

*different text is used to show what happens*